# SQL table definition best practice for column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these prices depending on monthly purchase
Source A:

```
| Purchase             | Price               |
| -------------------- | ------------------- |
| 1 - 5                | $1.50               |
| 6 - 7                | $1.40               |
| 8 - 10               | $1.30               |
| 11 and above         | $1.20               |
```

Source B:

```
| Purchase             | Price               |
| -------------------- | ------------------- |
| 1 - 5                | $5.00               |
| 6 - 7                | $4.50               |
| 8 - 10               | $4.00               |
| 11 and above         | $3.50               |
```

With the data presented above and I want to create the following table:

```
| Source_name | from_purchase    | to_purchase.   | fee  |
| ---------   | --------------   | -------------- | ---- |
| Source A    | 1                | 5              | 1.50 | 
| Source A    | 6                | 7              | 1.40 |  
| Source A    | 8.               | 10             | 1.30 | 
| Source A    | 11.              | 'and above'    | 1.20 | 
...
```

What value should I put in to_purchase column instead 'and above'? What would be the best practice?

I'll later do an inner join with another table using a BETWEEN statement

```
INNER JOIN fees f ON f.Source_name = t.Source_name AND t.transaction_count BETWEEN f.from_purchase AND f.to_purchase;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prefect use case for range data type.

```
CREATE TABLE txn_range_price_ref (
    source text,
    txn_qty_range int8range,
    fee numeric
);

INSERT INTO txn_range_price_ref
    VALUES ('Source A', '[1, 5000]'::int8range, 2.50),
    ('Source A', '[5001,7500]'::int8range, 2.40),
    ('Source A', '[7501,10000]'::int8range, 2.30),
    ('Source A', '[10000,)'::int8range, 2.20),
    ('Source B', '[1, 5000]'::int8range, 2.00),
    ('Source B', '[5001,7500]'::int8range, 1.50),
    ('Source A', '[7501,10000]'::int8range, 1.00),
    ('Source A', '[10000,)'::int8range, 0.50);
```

then You can do something like:

```
INNER JOIN txn_range_price_ref f ON f.Source_name = t.Source_name
    AND t.purchase_count <@ f.txn_qty_range
```

<@ operator: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html
range: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INFINITE

be careful with infinity with empty white spaces. because `select '[10000,)'::int8range;` is ok, but `select '[10000, )'::int8range;` will fail.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `money` as the type for `to_transaction` you can use +92233720368547758.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-money.html

Oher option could be to use -1 for `to_transaction` and when that is the case just check for `t.transaction_count > f.to_transaction` so your query has to change a bit

```sql
INNER JOIN fees f ON f.Source_name = t.Source_name 
AND ((f.to_transaction = -1) && (t.transaction_count > f.from_transaction))
OR (t.transaction_count BETWEEN f.from_transaction AND f.to_transaction;
```